# modal se abre muchas veces

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

cuando abro mi modal se abre un alert indicando que se abrio, pero si lo cierro y lo vuelvo a abrir, el mensaje se muestra 2 veces y si repito el proceso se muestra n veces

este es el javascript que abre mi modal

```
    function modificaru(idss){


            $('#md-mf').modal('show');
            $('#md-mf').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
                alert("abierto");
            });

            $('#md-mf').on('hide.bs.modal',function(){
                alert("cerrado");

            });
     }
```

espero puedan ayudarme

genero unas cartas atraves de una peticion ajax y las agrego asi:

```
window.onload=function(){

          var nombre = localStorage.nombre;
          var tip=localStorage.tipo;
          $('.nombre-user').text(nombre);
          $('.tipo-user').text(tip);


          jQuery.ajax({
            url:'../assets/php/cargartrabajadores.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            cache: false,
            data:{idvinedo:localStorage.idvinedo}
          })
          .done(function(respuesta){
             var nombret=respuesta.trabajadores.nombre;
             var tipot=respuesta.trabajadores.tipo;
             var emailt=respuesta.trabajadores.email; 

             for (let i = 0; i < nombret.length; i++){
              cuadros.push(i);
              let tipo;
              if (tipot[i]=='enologo') {
                tipo="Enólogo";
              }else{
                tipo="Agrónomo";
              }

              $("#user-list-c").after('<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8" style="margin-top:1.5%;"><div class="card card-n'+i+'" style="margin: 0%;"><div class="card-header" id="trab-t'+i+'"> <h3>'+tipo+'</h3></div><hr style="margin-top:-2%;height:1px;"><div class="card-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5"><p id="name-t'+i+'">'+nombret[i]+'</br>  '+emailt[i]+'</p> </div><div class="col-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7"><div class="row"><div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 csb1"><button type="button" id="btn-mf-us'+i+'" onclick="modificaru(this.id)" class="btn btn-warning btn-md btn-md-us float-right" style="margin-left:-20%;">Modificar</button></div> <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md float-left" id="btn-el-us'+i+'" onclick="EliminarTrabajador(this.id)">Eliminar</button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
              } 
          })
          .fail(function(resp){
            console.log(resp.responseText);
          })
          .always(function(){
          });

      };
```

donde atraves del for les asigno un id a cada carta para poder identificarlas

Comment: como estas haciendo el evento click para llamar a esa función? puedes colocarla en la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar un poco más de código?

Comment: edite la pregunta y coloque la funcion donde creo las cartas donde esta el boton que crea el boton que abre el modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu codigo el bind del evento se realiza cada ves que se muestra el modal. Deberias sacar el bindeo del metodo modificaru y hacerlo en el onload de la pagina. El metodo modificaru quedaria asi:

```
function modificaru(idss){
        $('#md-mf').modal('show');
}
```

y en window.load agregar el bind del alert

```
    window.onload=function(){
        $('#md-mf').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
            alert("abierto");
        });

        $('#md-mf').on('hide.bs.modal',function(){
            alert("cerrado");

        });
    ........
```

Comment: me funciono pero encontre que si le asignaba el metodo unbind de jquery, tambien solucionaba el problema.

Comment: claro pero es mejor hacer el bind solo una vez que hacerlo simpre que se habre el modal. El umbind es muy buena solucion cuando no queda de otra que hacer el bind siempre.